# Record or Stream music on Audio source (ALSA/pulseaudio) GNURADIO

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi3, alsa, gnuradio, pulseaudio

With my smartphone i can stream music by bluetooth on raspbery pi (I use pulse audio). I wouldlike now to record this song or to put this song directly on my Audio source on GNU RADIO.

[ALSA/Pulse audio capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdSCl.png)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You might want to mention you use bluetooth between phone and Pi, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution (on chat IRC #Pulseaudio) !

if you want to record audio from bluez source :

```
arecord -f cd > name.wav
```

if you want to stream audio from bluez source (with smartphone) in Audio source (GNU RADIO) :

Follow this tutorial : http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/ALSAPulseAudio

Modify Device name if necessary.